# Linking lists numbers in text in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I can't seem to find a solution to the following issue I am trying to solve.  I am creating a document using lists like this:

1.0.0 Blah Blah Blah

1.1.0 more blah blah

1.1.1 some more

2.0.0 Blah2 Blah2

2.1.0 See section 1.1.0

I want to link the list number 1.1.0 to the 1.1.0 in the text of 2.1.0 so that if 1.1.0 gets changed, to say 1.1.2 by adding text above it so it shifts down, it will automatically update in 2.1.0 to 'see section 1.1.2'

Can I do this?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a cross-reference.

1. Positon cursor where you want the number to be generated
2. Choose `References` Ribbon
3. Click `Cross-Reference`
4. Set `Reference Type`=`Numbered Item`
5. Set `Insert Reference to:` = `Paragraph Number`
6. Select which item you want the pointer to in the `For which numbered item` selection
7. Optionally check `Include above/below' if you want to automatically append whether reference is above or below current position.
8. Click `Insert`

Note--it will not update the reference real-time, but you can update it various ways:

- `right-click`-`Update Field`
- go into `Print Preview`
- select the entire document (Ctrl + A) and press F9

Comment: Also, selecting the entire document (`Ctrl + A`) and pressing `F9` will update all the fields that have changed